# How to reuse object property when defining the object?

Tags: php

How can I use $this in object key's value?

```
$data = (object) [
   'name'  => 'john',
   'other' => $this->name.' , wellcome',
];
```

what can I use for $this ?

Comment: You can't. The construct does not exist before it's initialized. But if you want to limit the places where you need to change stuff, why not `$name='john';$data=(object)['name'=>$name,'other'=>"{$name} , wellcome'];`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a synthetic local variable, then reuse it:

```
$data = (object) [
    'name'  => ($name = 'john'),
    'other' => $name.' , wellcome',
 ];
```

Use at your own risk.

https://3v4l.org/XmVc5